# Systemd: stop the main process (or the service) when a subprocess crash

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, cgroups

I have two programs that I called `program1` and `program2` which perform a main task of two operations. When `program1` start running it pipe its results to `program2` which performs the final result. Because both programs must run continuously, I implemented a systemd service for this and here is the content of `/lib/systemd/system/servers.service` file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Start servers
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/servers >> /var/log/servers.log
Restart=always
TimeoutStartSec=100
User=root

ExecStartPre=killall -w -q program1 && killall -w -q program2
User=root

ExecStopPost=killall -w -q program1 && killall -w -q program2
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When run the service, systemd create two process to realize the task, here you can see the status.

```
sudo service servers status
# result
● servers.service - Start servers
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/servers.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-06-29 21:00:27 UTC; 2h 5min ago
 Main PID: 11942 (server)
   CGroup: /system.slice/servers.service
           ├─11942 program1
           └─11944 program2
```

when one of the program crash the service is still in it running state which is not logically correct because the main task is stopped.

Please I will like to know if it is possible to implement such a situation with systemd services? If so, how?

Comment: if the programs are connected by a pipe, then when one end of the pipe closes, further reads or writes on the other end will get eof or an errors.  Isnt this what you observe?

Comment: Thank @meuh, In fact both programs work as servers. The first program (program1) just knows he writing to a file and the file here is our stdout. And the second one is reading to a file and the here is stdin. When the pipe broke the don't stop, I think they know about the availability of resources.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that, When the first program crash, the service restart automatically. Now I want to work on cron jobs to check if the second process still alive.